# Remove showing Ember Handlebars Indentation Error in terminal

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

```
<h2> Login Here </h2>
<form {{action="authenticate" on = "submit"}}>
    {{input type = "text" value=username placeholder="username"}}
    {{input type = "password" value=password placeholder="password"}}
    <button type = "submit"> Login </button>
</form>
```

Even this simple Ember program showing indentation error, which is not making any problem to run the code, but still it's irritating. Please find a solution to remove showing the indentation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember template lint by default uses 2-spaces for indentation. It looks like you're using either 4 spaces or tabs.

This should remove your linting error:

```
<h2> Login Here </h2>
<form {{action="authenticate" on = "submit"}}>
  {{input type = "text" value=username placeholder="username"}}
  {{input type = "password" value=password placeholder="password"}}
  <button type = "submit"> Login </button>
</form>
```

Also, I don't know how familiar you are with linting, but it's not *required* to be fixed for a program to be correct. It's only purpose is to help with code-style so that there can be consistency on larger projects with multiple team members.

Depending on which linter you have installed, (maybe this one: https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint), you can change the rules to fit your code style: https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/master/docs/rules.md

Comment: Am I able to set the indentation as **TAB** instead of 2 spaces?

Comment: looks like this one: https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/fba0b1e737afe9e90824b00fcdf27122219a9c4a/docs/rule/block-indentation.md